# Jquery key press call ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

i have written an event for pressing "Enter" to submit the chat,
but the problem is that event is being called 2 times where else i am pressing the key only once

```
$(document).on("keypress",function(event){
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        if(keycode == "13")
        {
            var content = $('.khung-nhap #content-div #content').html();
            $.ajax({
                url:"app/namsensei.php",
                type:"post",
                data:{content:content},
                beforeSend:function(){$(".khung-nhap #content-div span").html("Waiting second ...");},
                success:function(dulieu){
                    $('.khung-nhap #content-div #content').html("");
                    $(".khung-nhap #content-div span").html("Type content and press enter");

                }
            });
        }

});
```

Comment: have you tried `keyup`

Comment: One thing that might be wrong could be in the way this whole statement is executed. Does the binding to $(document) happen twice?

Answer (score 0):

Actually You need to attach the event to only that form or input not to whole document.

```
$('input').on("keypress",function(event){
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

        if(keycode == "13")
        {
            var content = $('.khung-nhap #content-div #content').html();
            $.ajax({
                url:"app/namsensei.php",
                type:"post",
                data:{content:content},
                beforeSend:function(){$(".khung-nhap #content-div span").html("Waiting second ...");},
                success:function(dulieu){
                    $('.khung-nhap #content-div #content').html("");
                    $(".khung-nhap #content-div span").html("Type content and press enter");

                }
            });
        }

});
```